# Reactjs - Argument type is not assignable to parameter type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am following some Reactjs course and faced issue which seems not to appear in this course..


**Customer.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Customer = () => {

    const [customerState, setCustomerState] = useState(
        {
            names: ['Martin', 'Andrea', 'Carol'],
            pickedName: 'Martin'
        }
    );

    const switchName = () => {
        const namePool = customerState.names;
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*3); //losowanie liczby w zakresie 0-2
        setCustomerState({pickedName: namePool[number]});
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Customer:</h2>
            <h3>{customerState.pickedName}</h3>
            <button onClick={switchName}>Change name</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Customer;
```

Mentioned code gives me error for line `setCustomerState({pickedName: namePool[number]});`:

[image]

and in Browser console i can see:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about the `names` field when updating the state. Simply include it using e.g. *object destructuring*.

```
setCustomerState((prevState) => ({
   ...prevState,
   pickedName: namePool[number],
}));
```

You app crashes in the line `namePool[number]` since `namePool` (`customerState.names`) is *undefined*.

```
const Customer = () => {
  const [customerState, setCustomerState] = useState({
    names: ['Martin', 'Andrea', 'Carol'],
    pickedName: 'Martin',
  });

  const switchName = () => {
    const namePool = customerState.names;
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    setCustomerState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      pickedName: namePool[number] as string,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Customer:</h2>
      <h3>{customerState.pickedName}</h3>
      <button onClick={switchName}>Change name</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm pretty new in React, could you expand your answer? how code should look like?

Comment: copy-paste, and got same error:
``Argument type function(any): any & {pickedName: string} is not assignable to parameter type ((prevState: {names: string[], pickedName: string}) => {names: string[], pickedName: string}) | {names: string[], pickedName: string}   Type string[] is not assignable to type undefined     Type function(any): any & {pickedName: string} is not assignable to type (prevState: {names: string[], pickedName: string}) => {names: string[], pickedName: string} ``

Comment: @gipcu I posted whole component. It doesnt throw any errors

Comment: no idea why this does not work for me.

Comment: @gipcu Updated my answer - please check it. Just copy my code and paste in your editor.

Comment: i have posted and answer based on your tips from your core answer

Answer (score 0):

**@kind user** made me think and i came up with solution.

As he mentioned names must be defined again because switchName overrides useState so i have changed:

```
setCustomerState({pickedName: namePool[number]});
```

into

```
setCustomerState({names: namePool, pickedName: namePool[number]});
```

and it's all working fine now.

Comment: _"names must be defined"_ - this is handled by the _object destructuring_ I mentioned :) Anyways this is interesting why it doesnt work for you.